# Make a query in SPARQL with DataType Property

Tags: sparql

I'm working with an ontology OWL and making a query about it.

My query is:

"PREFIX a: http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Indoor.owl# "
+ "SELECT ?X "
+ "WHERE { ?X a:hasDay a:" + day + " . "
+ " ?X a:hasRoom a:" + room + " . "
+ " ?X a:hasStartTime a:" + startTime +" }";

At the moment to make the query, the console of NetBeans throw me:

Undefined object property used in query: http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Indoor.owl#hasStartTime

But hasStartTime in the ontology isn't an object property, it is a data type (int).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value of the Java variable `startTime` is e.g. 420 (7am), if you look at your SPARQL query, the last triple pattern is made by

`?X a:hasStartTime a:` plus value of ``startTime,

i.e. it results in

`?X a:hasStartTime a:420`

RDF literals have to be put in quotes without a prefix - it's a literal and not a prefixed URI, e.g.

`?X a:hasStartTime 420`

or to make the datatype more explicit (for integer values the above is just a shortcut)

`?X a:hasStartTime "420"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>`

Comment: hasStarTime is an integer (in fact is a time but in minutes e.g. 7 am =  420), the data of hasStartTime is only an integer.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't change the reason for your error. I just took an example of a literal value because you didn't show your data The problem remains the same, you took a prefix before the literal value. I can adapt my answer.

Comment: I change my query:  The query is PREFIX a: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Indoor.owl#> SELECT ?X WHERE { ?X a:hasDay a:Thursday .  ?X a:hasRoom a:Bedroom .  ?X a:hasStartTime 528 }

Comment: Is the query Ok? If hasStartTime is an integer? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Syntactically it's ok. I don't know if it matches your data, but shouldn't you simply try it out? I mean you have the code and the data.