# Create data property XSD:string with Jena

Tags: sparql, jena, owl, ontology

the problem sounds so simple: I would like to create an data property for an individual as XSD:string in my ontology.

I can create properties of XSD:DateTime, XSD:Float or XSD:int, but if I use XSD:string, I get a untyped property!

I created a minimal example, which create an ontology with one class, one individual an two data properties. A DateTime, which works like expected and one string, which has no type in the ontology.

I tried with Jena versions 3.4 and 3.0.1 and have no idea who to fix it.

```
package dataproperty;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDatatype;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory;

public class DataProperty {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    String OWLPath = "DataProp.owl";
    try{
        String NS = "http://www.example.org/ontology.owl#";
    //Create Ontology
           model.createClass(NS+"Test");
           Resource r = model.createResource(NS+"Test");
           model.createIndividual(NS+"Indi1", r);
           r = model.createResource(NS+"Indi1");
           model.createDatatypeProperty(NS+"Name");
           model.createDatatypeProperty(NS+"Date");
    //Add Data Properties
           Property p = model.getProperty(NS+"Name");
           model.add(r, p, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral("MyName", XSDDatatype.XSDstring));
           p = model.getProperty(NS+"Date");
           model.add(r, p, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral("2017-08-12T09:03:40", XSDDatatype.XSDdateTime));
    //Store the ontology
       FileOutputStream output = null;
       output = new FileOutputStream(OWLPath);
       model.write(output);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error occured: " + e);
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Literals are strings by default, so those values are strings.

Comment: But as far as I know you should always specify the data type, that I get "MyName"^^XSD:string isn't it correct?

Comment: Looks like string typing has changed in RDF 1.1 vs RDF 1.0, but I suppose Jena uses RDF 1.0 "plain literals" for strings, [as the documentation suggests](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/typed-literals.html).

Comment: Actually, [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/migrate_jena2_jena3.html#rdf11-plain-literals) it says: "The datatype of a plain literal with no language tag (also called a "simple literal") has datatype xsd:string."

Comment: That is correct. Also, see the [Jena explanation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/migrate_jena2_jena3.html#rdf11-plain-literals)

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thanks!
But then I am faced to a new Problem. How can I query this with SPARQL?
Regarding:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036787/make-a-query-in-sparql-with-datatype-property
It should be worked out like this, but I did not find a valid query:
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX sa: <http://www.example.org/ontology.owl#> SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE{{?name sa:Name "MyName".}}

Comment: Are the namespaces correct? I don't see the protocol `http` . And why two curly braces around the triple pattern?

Comment: If this doesn't solve the issue: As far as I remember, there was a flag to distinguish between SPARQL based on RDF 1.1 and RDF 1.0 - but I forgot where this was documented. @AndyS should know it. It was something with `JenaRuntime`

Comment: Thanks AKSW, my query works in Jena, but not with Protege. So the query seems correct. I could not find anything about a flag, but for me it is not important...
A work around is to use language tags, that it can be queried with _SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE{?name sa:Name "MyName"@en.}_ in Protege

Answer (score 4):

It is not untyped in RDF 1.1 - it's written in short form (better compatibility).

e.g.
https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/
Section 2.5.1

"If there is no datatype IRI and no language tag, the datatype is xsd:string."